# Ordering of basis elements of a Lie-group representations tensor product

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let's consider a Lie Group $G$ and its complex representation  $\textbf{N}$. Let's consider the decomposition
$$
\textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} = \oplus_{J}\textbf{r}_J 
$$
where $\textbf{r}_J$ are the irreducible representations (For simplicity, I consider the case with no degenerate subspaces).

First question:
Is $ \bar{\textbf{N}}\otimes\textbf{N} =  \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}}$ always true? Since the decomposition is the same, I would say yes. If I take $|a\rangle \in \textbf{N}$ and $|\bar{b}\rangle \in \bar{N}$, is the following equation true?
$$|a\bar{b}\rangle = |\bar{b}a\rangle\qquad (2)$$

I have some doubts about this last equality. Infact, If I use the Clebsh-Gordan decomposition for the group $G$
$$
|a\bar{b}\rangle = \sum_{I,i}C^{a\bar{b}}_{I,i}|I,i\rangle, \qquad (3)
$$
I can use $(3)$ to derive
$$
\langle c\bar{d}|a\bar{b}\rangle = \delta_{ac}\delta_{\bar{b}\bar{d}} = \sum_{I,i}(C^{c\bar{d}}_{I,i})^*C^{a\bar{b}}_{I,i}.\qquad (4)
$$
But, If I assume $(2)$ is true, I can write 
$$
\langle c\bar{d}|a\bar{b}\rangle = \langle \bar{d}c|a\bar{b}\rangle = \delta_{a\bar{d}}\delta_{c\bar{b}}= \delta_{ac}\delta_{\bar{b}\bar{d}}$$
which is obviously incorrect. I think $(2)$ is not true but I am not convinced.

Second question: If I consider $$ \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} \otimes \textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}} = \textbf{N}\otimes\textbf{N}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}}\otimes\bar{\textbf{N}}$$
can I write
$$
|a\rangle\otimes |\bar{b}\rangle\otimes|c\rangle\otimes|\bar{d}\rangle =|a\rangle\otimes |c\rangle\otimes|\bar{b}\rangle\otimes|\bar{d}\rangle 
$$
and so
$$
|a\bar{b}\rangle\otimes|c\bar{d}\rangle  = |ac\rangle\otimes|\bar{b}\bar{d}\rangle  ?
$$
I am making a lot of confusion with the order of indices.

Comment: Probably but since the states I consider are implicitly one particles stases I would like to read answer by physicists.

Comment: That they are one-particle states is completely irrelevant in this case. I've given an answer and voted to migrate to [math.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation
$$ A\otimes B \cong B\otimes A$$ 
is always true for any tensor product - the tensor product is commutative in the sense that
$$ A\otimes B \to B\otimes A, a\otimes b\mapsto b\otimes a$$
is an isomorphism. However, your equation $(2)$ does not make sense. If you write an equation like $\lvert a \bar b \rangle = \lvert \bar a b \rangle$, both sides have to lie *in the same space*, but the l.h.s. lies in $N\otimes \bar N$ and the r.h.s. in $\bar N \otimes N$. Although they are isomorphic, they are not the same space, so this equation is neither true nor false, it simple doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your "always" is probably a bit strong, especially as you give the isomorphism. For Lie groups this is true, as the representations are (essentially) modules over a cocommutative Hopf algebra. If one drops the cocommutative part, then it becomes less trivial (it might still be true, but with a different isomorphism).